# Export user input history from OCaml utop to file

Tags: ocaml, utop

When I'm using OCaml `utop` every line of the input and output is printed into the console:

```
───┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───
   │ Welcome to utop version 2.10.0 (using OCaml version 4.14.0)! │
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Type #utop_help for help about using utop.

─( 22:17:51 )─< command 0 >─────────────────────────────{ counter: 0}─
utop # let x = 50;;
val x : int = 50
```

Is it possible to export each of user inputs and outputs from `utop` session into specific file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is saved by default at ~/.utop-history .
Isn't that enough for your purpose?

You can also change location and file size by manipulating UTop.history_file_name and other variables.

Comment: There are also two utop directives to save a session to a specific file: #utop_stash and #utop_save.